# How to mock request method in phpunit mockery?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I started using mockery so I have a problem in doing my unit test . I want to test authenticate middleware , I passed one condition for `expectsJson` so I need one more pattern to return true from `expectesJson` like below but not success

Authenticate.php

```
protected function redirectTo($request)
{
    if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
        return route('login');
    }
}
```

AuthenticatTest.php

```
class AuthenticateTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic unit test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testMiddleware()
    {
      $request = Request::create(config('app.url') . '500', 'GET',[],[],[],['REMOTE_ADDR'=>'127.0.0.1:8000']);
      $middleware = new Authenticate($this->createMock(Factory::class));
      $class = new \ReflectionClass(Authenticate::class);
      $method = $class->getMethod("redirectTo");
      $method->setAccessible(true);
      $expectedStatusCode = 401;
      $this->assertContains("http://",$method->invokeArgs($middleware,[$request]));
    }

    public function testMiddlewareElse()
    {
      $this->mock(Request::class, function($mock) {
        $mock->shouldReceive("expectsJson")
          ->once()->andReturn(true);
      });

      $request = Request::create(config('app.url') . '200', 'POST',[],[],[],['REMOTE_ADDR'=>'127.0.0.1:00']);
      $middleware = new Authenticate($this->createMock(Factory::class));
      $class = new \ReflectionClass(Authenticate::class);
      $method = $class->getMethod("redirectTo");
      $method->setAccessible(true);
      $this->assertContains("",$method->invokeArgs($middleware,[$request]));
    }
}
```

> testMiddlewareElse is failed , How to return true for `$request->expectsJson`

Comment: *You should not mock the Request facade. Instead, pass the input you desire into the HTTP helper methods such as get and post when running your test. Likewise, instead of mocking the Config facade, call the Config::set method in your tests.* from https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mocking

Comment: @apokryfos can you provide some examples! I already did that by reading that link

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could test a request for the authentication middleware. Assume that you have a route that requires authentication that is managed by `UserController@dashboard` (or similar):

```
public function testMiddleware() {
      // You could disable the other middleware of the route if you don't want them to run e.g.
      // $this->withoutMiddleware([ list of middleware to disable ]);
      $mockController = $this->prophecy(UserController::class);
      //This is if the middleware passes and the controller method is called, use shouldNotBeCalled if you expect it to fail 
      $mockController->dashboard(Prophecy::any())->shouldBeCalled();
      $this->app->instance(
         UserController::class, 
         $mockController->reveal()
      );
      $this->json("GET", url()->action("UserController@dashboard"));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution ! I need to pass mock class in invoke params ...;)

```
public function testMiddlewareElse()
{
  $mock = $this->mock(Request::class, function($mock) {
    $mock->shouldReceive("expectsJson")
      ->once()->andReturn(true);
  });

  $request = Request::create(config('app.url') . '200', 'POST',[],[],[],['REMOTE_ADDR'=>'127.0.0.1:00']);
  $middleware = new Authenticate($this->createMock(Factory::class));
  $class = new \ReflectionClass(Authenticate::class);
  $method = $class->getMethod("redirectTo");
  $method->setAccessible(true);
  $this->assertContains("",$method->invokeArgs($middleware,[$mock]));
}
```